# Is using the developement server from Werkzeug/Flask for a local app fine?

Tags: python, flask, webserver, wsgi, werkzeug

Hey !
I have a local app, packaged with Flask and Werkzeug, which launches a Werkzeug server on the client's computer, allowing the user to use the web app from their computer. It is not connected to a global server. Would it be fine using the development server for this?

The reasons I've seen for not using Werkzeug's development server in production are the debugger allowing for arbitrary code execution, and the mono-thread server, which is bad if several users are in during the same period.

Those don't seem to be problematic here, so are there any other issues I should be aware of?

Here's the server parts of my code, in case they are any options I should have as a fail-safe :

- run.py :

```py
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
     run_simple('localhost', 5000, app, use_debugger=False, use_reloader=False)
```

- app.py :

```py
import werkzeug 
from flask import Flask, render_template

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # To avoid problems with Pyinstaller
    template_folder = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'templates')
    static_folder = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'static')
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_folder, static_folder=static_folder)
else:
    app = Flask(__name__)
```

PS: I'm aware that Flask comes with Werkzeug preinstalled, but I've seen in a tutorial it's recommended to open Werkzeug manually to avoid Pyinstaller causing trouble in the server's architecture.

Comment: Since you have named the key arguments already, your question is asking for no more than an option.